# Session data is not saved yii2

Tags: php, session, yii2

I set the session value in this function

```
public static function setSessionId($sessionId): void
    {
        Yii::$app->session->set("basket_id", $sessionId);
    }
```

sessionId I get in this function

```
public static function createSessionID(): ?Itinerary
    {

        $post = new Post();
        $itinerary = $post->postItinerary();

        if ($itinerary && $itinerary->session) {
            self::setSessionId($itinerary->session);

            var_dump($itinerary->session);
            var_dump(Yii::$app->session->get("basket_id"));

            $b = new self;
            $b->setAttributes(
                [
                    "session_id" => $itinerary->session,
                ]
                );
                $b->save();
            }

            return $itinerary;
        }

        return null;
    }
```

I added two var_dumps to this function to check that the ID exists and is added to the session, and this is indeed the case, everything works here and is added

But when I make a separate function to get the sessionID, I lose data from this session

```
public static function getSessionID()
    {
        var_dump(Yii::$app->session->get("basket_id"));

        $basketId_session = Yii::$app->session->get("basket_id");

        $session_id = false;

        if (!$session_id && $basketId_session) {
            $session_id = $basketId_session;
        }

        return $session_id;
    }
```

I do the same `var_dump(Yii::$app->session->get("basket_id")),` but here the value is already null, although this ID is in the previous function

What could be the problem and why is the data disappearing??

Comment: As per your code, it's tough to identify the issue. `$session = Yii::$app->session;
$allSessionData = $session->getAll(); print_r($allSessionData);` and check whether session is there. You have to debug line by line

Comment: What happens if you try it with `getFlash()` and `setFlash()` instead of `get()` and `set()`?